# GPIO.input(24) is coming back True when it shouldn't be (false button presses)

Tags: gpio, pi-2, rpi.gpio, breadboard

I have a button in a working circuit. Within sys/class/gpio/gpio24, value changes properly (it becomes 1 when pressed down, 0 otherwise).

When I use GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN) within python, GPIO.input(24) rapidly changes between 0 and 1 without the button being touched at all.

The really strange thing is, that after I run this program, when I go back to sys/class/gpio/gpio24, value now reflects that same issue. It changes back and forth between 0 and 1 without the button being pressed.

What could be the issue? What can I do to have GPIO.input(24) act normally?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I didn't have my circuit connected to the ground properly. Don't know why that would cause such an issue though.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.